# == and eq Operators

Tags: scala

```
scala> val x = "a"
x: String = a

scala> val y = "a"
y: String = a
```

As I understand, `==` will call `equals` (value equality).

```
scala> x == y
res18: Boolean = true
```

But, `x eq y`, unexpected to me, shows true. `eq`, as I understand, checks for `object identity`.

```
scala> x eq y
res19: Boolean = true
```

Is the `Scala` compiler smart enough to return the same (identity) String object? I believe the term is [interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Or, is `eq` actually performing a value equality?

Comment: As a counterpart to the other answers, try `new String("a") eq new String ("a")`. You'll get `false`, since every constructor invocation by definition creates a distinct instance.

Comment: @RandallSchulz - when I ran your example in REPL, the following warning preceded the output of **false**: `<console>:9: warning: comparing a fresh object using `eq' will always yield false
              new String("a") eq new String("a")
                              ^`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scala's String is actually [Java.Lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html), which in fact uses interning - see Scala [Reference](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src//library/scala/Predef.scala#L1) -

```
type String        = java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 2):

Otávio is right, it should be the same as in Java.

To extend: the [documentation of eq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyRef) has quite a good explanation of what's expected of equality methods:

> When overriding the `equals` or `hashCode` methods, it is important to ensure that their behavior is consistent with reference equality. Therefore, if two objects are references to each other `(o1 eq o2)`, they should be equal to each other `(o1 == o2)` and they should hash to the same value `(o1.hashCode == o2.hashCode)`.