# val assignment in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala, val are the variables which can't be modified, ie their reassignment is not allowed.but in following code, I can reassign val,though it is reassigned to same object(it's a mutable map):

```
val treasureMap = Map[Int, String]()
treasureMap += (1 -> "Go to island.")
treasureMap += (2 -> "Find big X on ground.")
treasureMap += (3 -> "Dig.")
```

So it gives impression that val can be reassigned to same object but not to another object.

Also,

```
val str1 = "Hi"
val str2 = "Hi"
println(str1.eq(str2))
```

Output of this code is true,meaning only one instance of a string literal is there.

Going by all this behaviour, why following code gives compilation error when I try to reassign str1 to same object:

```
str1 = "Hi"
```

Here, I am assigning str1 back to very same object it initially referred to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea behind `val` is to protect re-assigning the value.

example,

```
scala> val data = 100
data: Int = 100

scala> data = 200
<console>:13: error: reassignment to val
       data = 200
            ^
```

Since scala also have mutable collections, like the `mutable.Map` you are using in example it lets you mutate the data but not the re-assignment.

```
scala> val treasureMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
treasureMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = Map()

scala> treasureMap += (1 -> "Go to island.")
res65: treasureMap.type = Map(1 -> Go to island.)
```

try re-assigning now, which won't let you do that because your variable is `val`

```
scala> treasureMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
<console>:13: error: reassignment to val
       treasureMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
                   ^
```

Same with any data structure.

```
scala> val str1 = "some string"
str1: String = some string

scala> str1 = "some another string"
<console>:13: error: reassignment to val
       str1 = "some another string"
            ^
```

Answer (score 3):

when you assign a Map (or a collection in general) you are assigning a label to the entry point of the collection (to put it simply).

So when you write

```
treasureMap += (1 -> "Go to island.")
```

you are not assigning anything new to `treasuremap`, you are just adding an element to the same Map, and the "label refers to the same entry point.

Regarding

```
val str1 = "Hi"
val str2 = "Hi"
```

they are two string values wrapping java strings, hence the unexpected behavior. You may check this answer [== and eq Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644482/and-eq-operators) for clarification